# Hive timestamp type wrong

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Hi I have **10 timestamp data of "2016-08-12 16:00:00"**,I use "SparkSql in Java to create a DataSet and **insert overwrite data into Hive**. When I read all 10 data, I found some of it are `"2016-08-12 16:00:00"` and others are `"2016-08-12 04:00:00"`.I think it may because Hive uses 12-hour timestamp as 16 is 4 in afternoon,but the problem is they are not consistent.

I can sure that in Dataset ,timestamps are all `2016-08-12 16:00:00`

How can I understand this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It uses 24 Hours format. so both the date are in correct format.first one is 4 am and another one is 4 pm. and if you are writing from external system ,use '`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` format instead of `'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a'` format.

Comment: But I don’t know why they are not same, 16 looks like 24 hour format, but 4 looks like hive uses 12 hour format